# Do you receive a government's Legacy Bonus before you change governments?

Tags: civilization-6

The name "Legacy Bonus" sort of sounds like a bonus you'd only receive after you've adopted a different government. If I had to guess, though, I would say that you also receive it immediately. I am wondering if anybody can confirm this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "My Government" tab, you can view a list of all your legacy bonuses.
[image]

The legacy bonus is a small bonus you receive every x amount of turns while you are under the same government. The game's tooltip explains this fairly well and you can see the progression until the next bonus as well (the circle around the feather next to the +1 under the Legacy Bonuses).

**The bonuses are received "immediately" even if you have the same government WHEN they are attributed.** So in the screenshot for example, I have had the Communism government for 90-ish turns, so I receive a 14% bonus to production instead of the starting 10% because I receive a 1% bonus every 20 turns. Of course, I also still have bonuses to other things because of the legacy bonuses I earned while under other governments.